# Programmatically call "mousemove" event in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mousemove

Is there a possibility to programmatically call the **mousemove** event in jQuery?
Obviously, I'm not going to change the actual position of the cursor - it's impossible. All I want is re-call this event so all other scripts that have attached their handers to it will also be called.

Comment: Have you tried `.trigger('mousemove')`?

Comment: $( "#foo" ).trigger( "mousemove" ); -- did u try this

Answer (score 3):

To trigger event handlers bound to the mousemove event you can use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('#elementID').on('mousemove', function() {
     // do stuff
});

$('#elementID').trigger('mousemove'); // triggers above event handler
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried with trigger() before but I needed to perform a global call of this event. However, seems like I've solved this by triggering it to 'html' element.
Thanks.